# add a function on jquery smart wizard

Tags: php, jquery, smart-wizard

I want to input data from multiselect (right side) to database, I use the default form smart wizard from gentelella template, to get data from multiselect I make function:

```
function selectAll(theSel) {
var selLength = theSel.length;
for(i=selLength-1; i>=0; i--) {
    theSel.options[i].selected = true;
}
```

}

[image: how to solve it so that the data into the database]

I added this :

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" action="<?=site_url('index.php/biodata/commit'); ?>" method="POST" onsubmit="selectAll(document.getElementById('region_id_assign')); selectAll(document.getElementById('region_out_id_assign')); return;">
```

and change the code onfinish to true :

```
$.fn.smartWizard.defaults = {
selected: 0,  // Selected Step, 0 = first step
keyNavigation: true, // Enable/Disable key navigation(left and right keys are used if enabled)
enableAllSteps: false,
transitionEffect: 'fade', // Effect on navigation, none/fade/slide/slideleft
contentURL:null, // content url, Enables Ajax content loading
contentCache:true, // cache step contents, if false content is fetched always from ajax url
cycleSteps: false, // cycle step navigation
enableFinishButton: false, // make finish button enabled always
hideButtonsOnDisabled: false, // when the previous/next/finish buttons are disabled, hide them instead?
errorSteps:[],    // Array Steps with errors
labelNext:'Next',
labelPrevious:'Previous',
labelFinish:'Finish',
noForwardJumping: false,
onLeaveStep: null, // triggers when leaving a step
onShowStep: null,  // triggers when showing a step
onFinish: true  // triggers when Finish button is clicked
```

};

how to solve it so that the data into the database?

sorry, I'm new this time try using smart wizard